# How to make VimWiki open file directly in vim instead of VSCode

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

While using VimWiki, I linked to a file on my computer using

```
[[file:/path/to/file.py]]
```

And when I hit enter, it opens the file with VSCode.

I already when to the file in Finder, clicked 'Get Info' and selected 'Open with:' -> 'Other' but 'Vim' is not an option there.

Is there are to have a file link in VimWiki and when I hit enter have it open that python inside of vim?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for the interesting question: do you have `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` set? It sounds like you're on a mac, so it's probably using the default editor associated with that extension—there are ways to change this to MacVim, but not terminal vim. The docs point to `:help VimwikiLinkHandler`—you could remove the `file:` part and it should just work, or you can try the `gf` command (vim builtin)

Comment: Noob question, but yes I believe I have $EDITOR and $VISUAL set properly after reading other posts online. added those to my '.zshrc' and '.vimrc' just to test both. As far as Mac vim goes, I got that working, but what I actually want is to click on a file link in vim wiki and have it open that python file directly in vim, without opening up a new MacVim window if that makes sense.

Not sure if this is possible actually

Comment: Try it without the file: piece. If that doesn’t work try gf. If that doesnt work, You’ll need to check the help page i mentioned.